# How to bind on emitted value from eventemitter from the template

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-directive

I am learing how to make binding between the parent and the child using @Input, @Output and EventEmitter decorators.
in the following code

```
      @Output() newItemValue = new EventEmitter<string>();
```

i created an eventemitter that will emit a value when the method addNewItem is invoked on a string parameter.
in the body of addNewItem methos i call

```
this.newItemValue.emit(val);
```

i want to bind on this.newItemValue, so i did the following in the html file

```
<button appItemDetails (click) = addNewItem(newItem.value)>add new item</button>
<p (newItemValue)="onlyNewlyAddedItems($event)"></p>
```

but when i compile the App i revceive the error posted below.
please let me know how to bind on this.newItemValue from the template

**error**

```
Failed to compile.

src/app/app.component.html:4:40 - error TS2345: Argument of type 'Event' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.

4 <p (newItemValue)="onlyNewlyAddedItems($event)"></p>
                                         ~~~~~~

  src/app/app.component.ts:5:16
    5   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component AppComponent.
```

**app.component.ts**:

```
import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'InputOutputBindings';
  currentItem = 'TV';
  items = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4'];

  @Output() newItemValue = new EventEmitter<string>();

  addNewItem(val : string) {
    this.newItemValue.emit(val);
    console.log("add new item:" + val);
    this.items.push(val);
    console.log("add new item:" + this.items);
  }

  onlyNewlyAddedItems(val : string) {
    console.log("onlyNewlyAddedItems:" + val);
  }
}
```

**item-details.directive.ts**:

```
import { Directive, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
@Directive({
  selector: '[appItemDetails]',
  exportAs: 'customdirective'
})
export class ItemDetailsDirective {

  @Input() item : string = "";

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log("ngOnInit->:" + this.item)
  }

  ngOnChange() {}
}
```

**app.coponent.html**:

```
<h1 #test = customdirective appItemDetails [item]="currentItem">{{currentItem}}  item</h1>
<label>Add an item: <input #newItem></label>
<button appItemDetails (click) = addNewItem(newItem.value)>add new item</button>
<p (newItemValue)="onlyNewlyAddedItems($event)"></p>
```

Comment: Your `<p>` tag does not throw an event that is called `newItemValue`. You most likely want to set the value to a variable in your button click and display that using interpolation (e.g. `{{newItemValue}}`). In angular, using the `[prop]` or `{{prop}}` syntax means "binding to a display value or an input" and `(eventName)` means "binding to an event or an output".

Comment: @pascalpuetz would you please have a look at app.component.ts above...it has answers to your inquiries

Comment: @LetsamrIt, check out my answer.

Comment: @LetsamrIt I did not have any inquiries though? The problem that first came to my attention was that you try to bind an event `(newItemValue)` on a normal html tag `<p>`, which will never dispatch an event called `(newItemValue)`. Doing `<p (newItemValue)="myFunc()">` is roughly equivalent to `document.getElementById('myPElement').addEventListener('newItemValue', () => this.myFunc())`. Mind the 'roughly', it is not exactly the same, but the concept is.

Answer (score 0):

I've observed your question.

I think you misunderstood the concept.

In your example, you were using `EventEmitter` without necessary. Because if you do not have any parent/child situation you can handle adding new items with a simple button click.

So, I've reconstructed your example.

I've added a `test` component where I've added your textbox.

**test.component.html**

```
<h1 #test=customdirective appItemDetails [item]="currentItem">{{currentItem}} item</h1>
<label>Add an item: <input #newItem></label>
<button appItemDetails (click) = addNewItem(newItem.value)>add new item</button>
```

**test.component.ts**

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, Output } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'test',
  templateUrl: './test.component.html'
})
export class TestComponent {
  @Output() newItemAdded = new EventEmitter<string>();

  title = 'InputOutputBindings';
  currentItem = 'TV';

  addNewItem(value: string) {
    this.newItemAdded.emit(value);
  }
}import { Component, EventEmitter, Output } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'test',
  templateUrl: './test.component.html'
})
export class TestComponent {
  @Output() newItemAdded = new EventEmitter<string>();

  title = 'InputOutputBindings';
  currentItem = 'TV';

  addNewItem(value: string) {
    this.newItemAdded.emit(value);
  }
}
```

Then I've included `test` component as a child component under `app` component.

**app.component.html**

```
<test (newItemAdded)="newItemAdded($event)"></test>
<h3>TV items: </h3>
<div>
  <ul *ngFor="let item of items">
    <li>{{item}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, Output } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  items = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4'];

  newItemAdded(val : string) {
    console.log("onlyNewlyAddedItems:" + val);
    this.items.push(val);
  }
}
```

I've added an item list to your parent (`app`) component. So, now we can use `EventEmitter`, because we want to show the newly added `item` to the parent (`app`) component's list.

At the `test` component when `add new item` button is clicked the event is emitted, which is captured by the `app` component. And then we've added the new item to the existing `items` array.

See the demo very attentively.

Working demo at [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fdnrth?file=src/app/app.component.html).

Comment: Would you please tell me how to have my example working?.what I need to change or add?!i feel a bit lost when try to study your example..thanks

Comment: Please write in points what you don't understand.